# Python Regex to extract content between two specific tags

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract the content between `Tag2:` and `Tag3:`

I've used the following regex `Tag2:\s*(.* )\s*?Tag3:` but that doesn't seem to capture the content in between both the tags.

```
Tag1: 22

Tag4: Example sentence.

Tag3:

 - Desired sentence! 
- Desired sentence!
- Desired sentence!
- Desired sentence!

Tag2: This is the end.
```

Also, if I have a variable that contains all the tags, how can I include it in my regex.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Can you possibly help me with the solution as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
t1 = input("Tag1:")
t2 = input("Tag2:")
sent = input("Sentence:")
pattern = t1 + "(.*?)" + t2
print(" ".join(str(i) for i in re.findall(pattern, sent)))
```